# How to display Recent view product in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django, and I am looking for this answer. Please let me know how I can solve this issue. Suppose, if a user visits on my website and he clicks on any product then that product should be shown in recent view on his PC/Laptop, suppose if a user exit from website and after 2-3 hours he/she visit again then previous views product should be shown in his recent viewed product. and I want to do this without logging in a user, please let me know how I can do it.
if anybody has code for this please submit here or explain the process.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inbuilt function like you want but you can apple your own logic you have to made store user visited product in one sprat data base model with (auto_new_add=TRUE)this will add time and data automatically and right following logic after the login event that bring that story data bake(use time and date to identify resent visited product)
x = visted.objects.filter(time=time)